# The group of Mobius Transforms and their conjugates/reflections?

Tags: terminology, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

I'm looking at a group of transformations from $X \cup \lbrace \infty \rbrace$ to itself, where $X$ is a Hilbert Space, and ultimately I'm looking for an appropriate name for this group.

The elements of group, as it turns out to be the products of isometries and non-zero scaling operators on $X$ (where $\infty$ maps to itself) and inversions in spheres. As such, these maps locally preserve angles, but not necessarily orientation. This makes them **isogonal maps**. Moreover, they are also smooth (where appropriate).

I thought about calling this group the "isogonal group", but this suggests that it's the group of isogonal maps, and I'm not sure the two concepts perfectly line up. I have heard of [Liouville's Theorem of Conformal Mappings,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(conformal_mappings)) but given this is possibly infinite-dimensional and as far as I can tell, the techniques used for proving this theorem do use finite dimensions (things like Jacobeans), I'd prefer a different name.

Surely, on $\mathbb{C}$, there's a name already for the group of Mobius Transforms and their conjugates? If such a name already exists, I think this would be the perfect name for this  group.

Comment: Sadly the phrasing I've seen most often is something awkward like "group of conformal and anti-conformal maps". Some authors use "extended Möbius group".

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I don't suppose you have a reference for "extended Mobius group" to hand?

Comment: No, not in particular. From a web search it looks like it's even less common than I thought.